# Object Detection with TensorFlow Lite on jetson nano

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to real time object decetion with TensorFlow Lite on jetson nano. But I can't choice which YOLO version was given best FPS in TensorFlow Lite. Or should I use Tensorflow instead of TensorFlow Lite? And I want to ask that do YOLO V4 and V8 work in TensorFlow Lite? Can you write any source code?

I want to real time object decetion with TensorFlow Lite on jetson nano.